# Unable to send mails in PHP contact form using 000webhost webmail

Tags: php, email

I am using 000webhost webmail to receive emails using contact form but its not working.

**contact.php**

```
     <form  action="mailer.php" method="post">
<p>Name:</p>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<p>E-mail:</p>
<input type="text" name="email" />
<p>Subject:</p>
<input type="text" name="subject" />
<p>Message:</p>
<textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
<input class="send" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
</form>
```

**mailer.php**

```
     <?php

$to = "xxx@xxxxx.com";
$subject = "Support requested by ".$_POST['name'];
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$headers = 'From: '.$_POST['email'].'' . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: '.$_POST['email'].'' . "\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$body = $message;

@mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers );
header( 'Location:thankyou.php' ) ; //replace with landing page.
?>
```

Comment: What part isn't working? The message isn't sent? You are receiving error messages? Have you checked your logs?

Comment: First and foremost, remove the "@" from "@mail" so you will see an error if there is one.

Comment: i see the thankyou page but i dont recieve any email

Comment: My first guess would be that your web host is rejecting outgoing mail from the from address you supplied... some restrict outgoing mail to your domain.

Comment: Is the `mail()` function returning true or false? If `true`, then it's something PHP doesn't know about (blackholed, blocked, etc.). If `false`, then it's likely not allowed from the server, or you have an error in your code somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your html I tried it.
If you have chrome you can use the developer tool to debug and see if your requests are sent and if they are lending on the correct path :

[image]

In your mailer.php output the `$_POST` variable to make sure your data is landing there correctly,

```
echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

You may also need to validate your html :

```
<form  action="mailer.php" method="post">
  <p>Name:</p>
  <input type="text" name="name" >
  <p>E-mail:</p>
  <input type="text" name="email" >
  <p>Subject:</p>
  <input type="text" name="subject" >
  <p>Message:</p>
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  <input class="send" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: i tried the same code in godaddy webmail and its working fine

Comment: I responded to your question "My php contact form not sending" I thought it was a problem while sending a form. Good luck